# Store utm source from url to database when user signup

Tags: database, utm

I would like to keep the utm source data when a user visit my site via the url with utm source in order to see the efficiency of any source.

url example : http://www.mydomain.com/?utm_source=facebook&utm_medium=promoted&utm_campaign=welcome

I need to see the users who have been signed up from which source. The best is to keep the utm_source data in a column at users table in database.

I could not succeed to catch and insert the source data if the visitor signs up in that session. My site is php.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the `__utmz` cookie (automatically created by the Google Analytics tracking code) for all the "utm" related information. In PHP it should be: `$_COOKIE['__utmz']`.